# Gridview filter and sorting using LINQ

Tags: linq, gridview, .net-4.0

I'm upgrading a project to .net 4. My GridViews are using DataSets and implement filtering, sorting and paging using an ObjectDataSource.

What is the best practice to connect a GridView to a Linq query and implement sorting, filtering and paging?

Do i still use a DataSet and ObjectDataSource or is there a way to use another type of DataSource that let's me connect directly to a LINQ query result which handles the filtering, sorting and paging for me?

**Edit:**

There's busineseslogic in between the UI and DatabaseContext therefore connecting directly to my ORM isn't an option. It has to be against a LINQ query result (IQueryable). I'm using separate Insert/Update/Delete functions to handle business logic before talking to the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is keep your ObjectDataSource (ODS) but take the logic that you use to retrieve the data and put it into a class that uses Linq (or any other data access technology) to retrive the data for you.

To do this in the ObjectDataSource you specifiy the name of the class that will be doing the work for you e.g.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
                          TypeName="CustomDAL" 
                          SelectMethod="GetData"/>
```

This will make the ODS create an instance of the `CustomDAL` class and call the `GetData` method.

Sorting and paging are supported as well but its probably best to implement the actual logic yourself in relation to restricting data that is retrieved.

To enable paging you add `EnablePaging="True"` to the ODS declaration and on your SelectMethod you add StartRowIndex and PageSize handling them in your linq using the `Skip` and `Take` methods to give you the right records e.g.

```
var results= (from user in context.users 
          where user.UserId == userId
          select user).Skip(StartRowIndex).Take(PageSize).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks but the big advantage would be not having (to create) a function for each and every objectdatasource. Rather just passing the type and needed parameters or a linq query to 1 generic class.

Comment: You are probably better off creating own generic data access class then rather than use ODS and populate grid view by manually databinding